# TCL data structure, Need to extract, match, and compare

Tags: regex, string, structure, tcl

I am completely new to programming full-stop.
I have to come up with a program that checks cables that interconnect FPGAs. From the command prompt (TCL interface), I get the following after entering a command:

```
{A13-D1 CON_CABLE_HT3_25 [serial# of the cable] J1 {1V0 1V2 1V35 1V5 1V8 2V5 3V3} [another random serial number]}
```

Now this is repeated for every single port on the system. `A13` is the name of the port, that the cable is connected to. I need to match up the serial numbers of the cables, and then put them in an array or something. So if `A13` has the same serial number(of the cable) as `D1`, it would mean `A13` is connected to `D1`. So it could be written as `A13 D1`, which would make more sense.

After getting all the connections, I need to compare it against a configuration file, where all the connections are given.

I don't need someone to do this for me, I just dont know how to get started! Any ideas?

I'd like to do this in tcl as the all the commands that I would be using to get this data is in tcl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line looks like a brace-quoted Tcl list, which given that there's Tcl on the other side is entirely possible. That makes extracting information easy!

Assuming you've got the line in a variable called `line`, you can get the connection information with `lindex`:

```
set connectInfo [lindex $line 0 0]
```

Then you'd use `split` and a further `lindex` to get the two bits of that:

```
set port [lindex [split $connectInfo "-"] 0]
```

You could also use `regexp` to extract the information from `$connectInfo`:

```
# Anchored because we're matching the whole string
regexp {^(\w+)-\w+$} $connectInfo -> port
# You should check the result of regexp to see if the match actually succeeded
#    if {![regexp {^(\w+)-\w+$} $connectInfo -> port]} {
#        error "it didn't match! waaah!"
#    }
```

However, writing a regular expression tends to require knowing the format of the data quite well. (If you're using regular expressions, *put them in braces* as that avoids backslashitis.)

Comment: Thanks, now I have gotten all the connectors and the cables etc.

Comment: Thanks, now I have gotten all the connectors and the cables etc. What I need to do now is match it against data stored in another variable to make sure the connections are the same,returning any connections that shouldn't be there..Or any connections that are wrong! So e.g
$data1 => {{ S1.A1 S2.A1 } { S2.B1 S2.C2 }}
$date2 => {{ S2.C2 S2.B1 } { S1.A1 S2.A1 }}

So in each element it tells u the connection, for instance data[0]  is s1.A1 connected to S2.A1. They can be any format, so it shouldn't matter if it was S2.A1 S1.A1 in $data2 and S1.A1 S2.A1 in $data1, they are still the same connection

Comment: So How would I compare the two variables to test the connections. Please don't do this for me, any hints much appreciated!! I have looked at lsearch and whatnot but data structures just get so complex when I try to come up with an algorithm

Comment: @user3201970 The real idea I've got right now is to split the data into smaller logical pieces. If you can only see how to do one type of split at a time, do the bit that you can see and then look at how to process a single unit after splitting. It's how you tackle nearly any complicated task: break it down into simpler tasks. (And don't forget to “check the literature” for useful algorithms over graphs; it sounds like the sort of thing that is useful.)